# An "easy" graph problem I can't solve

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

The question is:

> A given graph is given with only weights 1 or 2 on its arcs. (I.e. each arc has a weight of 1 or a weight of 2)
>
> And a origin vertex s.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm that finds the shortest paths (most easy in weight that is) from s to the rest of the vertices.

I really don't have a better idea than perform the Dijkstra algorithm, but I know it is not the right answer. Help anyone?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-weighted-graph-weight-edge-1-2/

Comment: For another method, check the last section of this page: https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/01_bfs.html

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.

Answer (score 2):

For every edge $(u,v)$ with weight $2$, create a new node $w_{u,v}$. Discard the edge $(u,v)$, and instead of it add two edges $(u,w_{u,v})$ and $(w_{u,v},v)$ with weight $1$.

Now you can use a standard unweighted pathfinding algorithm, such as BFS.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I look at Dijkstra's algorithm on a weighted graph $G$ as actually an "efficient" BFS on an unweighted $G'$ graph -- where each edge $(u,v)$ of weight w in $G$ has been replaced by a path of length $w$ formed of unweighted arcs from $u$ to $v$.